# BTC Guild API Parsing Issue with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, bitcoin

I am trying to get some basic information from the BTC Guild API through AngularJS, but all it does is run in the error function and gives no output as to what the error is.  Firebug shows nothing in the error object when breaking in that function.  Any ideas?

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/bX3ar/11/

javascript:

```
angular.module('BTCGuild', []);

function BTCGuildCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://www.btcguild.com/api.php?api_key=').success(function (response) {
        $scope.error = 'response:' + response;
        $scope.unpaidRewards = response.user.unpaid_rewards;
    }).error(function (error, status) {
        $scope.error = 'error:' + error + status;
    });
}
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="btcguild.js"></script>
</head>
<html ng-app="BTCGuild">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="BTCGuildCtrl">
        <table>
            <p>{{unpaidRewards}}</p>
            <p>Error:{{error}}</p>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

1. You're going to get a "Cross Origin Request" error. Here's a snippet of the response after fixing it:
   `OPTIONS https://www.btcguild.com/api.php?api_key= No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`
2. [Take a look at these notes on how to properly format a JSFiddle for Angular](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/): Frameworks & Extensions should be **No Library - pure JS**, and **No wrap, in** . Also, you'll want to put this under **Fiddle Options: Body Tag** `<body ng-app="BTCGuild">`
3. Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bX3ar/14/

If you can get through the CORs issue, you'll see this work. Or if you put in a fake `response`, you can see it display properly.